# How to use Findstr regex to match a dash (-)?

Tags: regex, batch-file, findstr

Trying to use findstr to match text that follows the format below:

> ```
> PTB-14
> AIR-217
> ```

The problem I'm having is that I just can't seem to get `findstr` to match on the dash, `-`. I've created the script below in a batch file:

```
set dash=-
echo.%dash%
echo !dash! | findstr /i /r /C:- >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo "ERROR!" >&2
    )
```

I've tried the regex with `/C:-`, `/C:"-"`, `/C:"\-"` and `/C:"\\-"`. I just can't seem to get it matched. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to enable delayedexpansion, so `echo !dash!` wil be echoed literally. Use `echo -|findstr /C:"-"` or `echo %dash%|findstr /C:"-"`

Comment: ...or, if you insist on delayed expansion for some reason, `cmd /V /C echo ^!dash^! | findstr /I /C:"-"`; by the way, you should remove the `/R` option (no regex.) as you search for a literal character `-`; instead of `if ErrorLevel 1` you could also use the `||` operator: `... | > nul findstr /I /C:"-" || >&2 nul echo ERROR^^!`...

Comment: I wonder if a character class would help. If the dash is the first, last, or only character in the class, then it will be treated as a literal. For example: [-]

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no need to use a regular expression (`/R`), but you can use a literal search string `-`. And case-insensitivity (`/I`) does also not make much sense with non-letter characters.

Anyway, I think the problem in your code is that you do not have [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled, although you are trying to use it, so `echo !dash!` actually echoes `!dash!` literally.

To solve that, there are a few options:

1. Place `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` before your code and (optionally) place `endlocal` after it in order to enable delayed expansion in the parent `cmd` instance that executes your batch file, like this:

   ```cmd
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "dash=-"
   echo(%dash%
   echo(!dash!| > nul findstr /C:"-" || >&2 echo ERROR^^!
   endlocal
   ```
2. A pipe `|` initiates two new `cmd` instances for either side, which do not have delayed expansion enabled, even if the parenth `cmd` instance does. However, you can explicitly initiate another `cmd` instance on the left side of the pipe with delayed expansion enabled (`/V`):

   ```cmd
   set "dash=-"
   echo(%dash%
   cmd /V /C echo(^!dash^!| > nul findstr /C:"-" || >&2 echo ERROR!
   ```

   The exclamation marks are escaped (`^!`) in order for them not to be consumed by the parent `cmd` instance in case delayed expansion is enabled there; if not, the escaping does not harm.

In the above code fragments, I additionally changed the following:

- `set dash=-` has become `set "dash=-"`, as this is the most secure syntax that prevents unintended trailing white-spaces and accepts even special characters like `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>` and `|`;
- `echo.` has become `echo(`, which is the only reliable syntax, although it looks odd;
- the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of the pipe `|` has disappeared, because it would also have been echoed;
- `if ErrorLevel 1` has been replaced by the conditional command concatenation operator `||`, which lets the following command execute only in case an error occurred, or, technically spoken, in case the exit code of the previous command was non-zero;
- `echo "ERROR!" >&2` has been changed to `>&2 echo ERROR^^!` or `>&2 echo ERROR!` in order to avoid the quotation marks `""` and the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> before `>&2` to be echoed also; the double-escaping of the `!` is needed to display it in case delayed expansion is enabled;